# Add a static website from Azure Storage Account to an Asp.net MVC app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, typescript, azure, kendo-ui

I have to include a React application inside a dotnet MVC project. I have a simple React application that only contains a KendoUI grid.

- I did a build of the React application and uploaded it as a static website using Azure Storage Account.
- I then created an Azure CDN that points to the static React application

Here is what I need to do:

I have the following code (ASP.net MVC):

[image]

The commented div is the div that contains the old grid (the one to be replaced with the static React application).

I would like to add the static React application in the test div (the one with the id "scheduleSitesGrid2")

I configured my static React app to look for that exact same div (here is the index.tsx):

[image]

That being said, is there a way I can easily include that react application in the MVC app using Azure CDN? I could not find any other question regarding adding a React app to MVC using CDN.

I tried to include the CDN in a script tag, but that did not work. I am also wondering that since the React app is hosted as a static site, it is already built, so I might not be able to add it in the MVC div (since it is already inserted into the index.html file of the React app as shown in the following picture). I would then need to upload all the app to Azure besides the index.html. Am I right?

[image]

Thank you very much!

Peace!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have an MVC Web App hosted using some App Service Plan, and a React application which has no server side code execution just Javascript?

If that's correct then you will certainly be serving content from two separate domains: One for your Web App, presented via CDN; and one for the storage account, hosting the static content, which is only presented via the storage account URI.

The both can indeed be presented via a single CDN endpoint, but you would need to use the premium tier and make use of URL rewrite rules.  You would have your default route configured to that of your Web App URI, then you would configure a rewrite rule to, for example, rewrite (translate) "/static/..." to "https://{{yourstaticstorage}}.storage.azure.com/yourstaticpath/...".

Verizon Premium rewrite is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-verizon-premium-rules-engine-reference-features#url-rewrite

If you don't want to use Verizon Premium, you could also take a look at Azure Front Door.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/frontdoor/

Essentially, Front Door is CDN on steroids.  It has built in WAF and allows you to configure routing rules.  Do compare the pricing before going this route as I'm fairly sure you have to pay for each routing rule.

You could also pull the static content in code before delivering it but this wouldn't be cached on the CDN since every dynamic page visited would require execution.  You're better off creating a routing rule and using relative paths to the static content which are retrieved and cached by the CDN / Front Door.

Comment: Yeah, that's it :) I have a dummy React app that is only displaying a hardcoded grid. I would like to put this app in a cdn and be able to reuse it in a dotnet MVC app. I know that there are a lot of tools that allow people to include react in their MVC app repository, but I was wondering if that was doable using CDN.

I see that when a React app is built, the App component is rendered in index.html. However, I would like to render this App component in a MVC app.

Comment: Sure you can do that with an MVC app.  You can include your script files with your app deployment and they'll just be served as static content.  You do then of course need to put relative script references in when rendering the page `<script src="/whatever/static/react.js></script>`  This static content will be cached by the CDN under a single domain.

Comment: Okay but would they need to be in the same repo as my app? I wanted to have a Azure CDN dedicated to my React app and then use the link of the cdn in my MVC app (ex: <script src="the-cdn-link.azureedge.net"></script> in the cshtml file).

Comment: If you want the same CDN endpoint for MVC and React, without using URL rewrite, yes they need to be in the same repo.  Otherwise you need to use URL rewrite, or have 2 separate CDN endpoints - one for MVC, one for React, or just one for React using absolute URLs in your script references.

Comment: Okay so I am in the situation where I have 2 CDNs. Let's say that I build the react app and save it to Azure blob storage and then create a CDN that points to this app. I will be able to include that CDN in my MVC app and then add this app in a div? (Like I showed in my post)

Comment: Yes you can do that no problem.  Don't forget about Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) - If the CDN supports it.  Your client will be using the origin (hostname) of your MVC app to access the domain of your React CDN.  See here for more info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-cors

Comment: That is exactly what I needed! I was getting  CORS issues! Thanks!